# Can a Scan (build & tests) be reused in Gym (build) when creating an archive?

Tags: fastlane

I have a project which builds and tests in 10 minutes. If the Fastlane Scan does not throw an error then I build an archive with the Fastlane Gym.

In total it takes almost 18 minutes.

I would like to decrease a delivery time for an app build and the first idea is to reuse a build from Scan in Gym. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain, but I don't think it's possible. I think Xcode always does a full build, not an incremental build, when archiving, so it doesn't matter what's already there. Also, usually you test with the Debug configuration and archive with the Release configuration. You can pass a `configuration` parameter to `scan` telling it to do a Release build. If you look at the scheme in your project or workspace, it's probably set up to test with Debug (when you use cmd-U in Xcode). You may or may not have issues unit testing with Release, depending on your codebase. At least you might have to modify some tests.

There are ways to speed up your build with Xcode. Maybe something here will help:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2190/_index.html